# How to import a function that I've made in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Sorry to ask such elementary thing...

I've made this `factorial.py` file:

```
# Find the factorial of a number
def fact(n):
    p = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        p = p*i
    return p
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input('Enter an integer to find the factorial of: '))
    f = fact(n)
    print('Factorial of {0}: {1}'.format(n, f))
```

and saved in `C:\Users\usersname`

Then in new `idle` I wrote `from factorial import fact`,
but it resulted in an error as on the following image:

[image]

Comment: It seems to me your file contains a copy-paste from an interactive interpreter session i.e. the beginning of a REPL session.

Comment: Also, please post the text of the error message *as text*, not as an image.

Comment: To add to the comment by @juanpa.arrivillaga Python tells you what piece of code was responsible for the error. Here, it is line 1 of `factorial.py`, and this line starts with "python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64bit)|...", which is obviously not valid pyton code. Hence the `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Your file doesn't seem to be python code. However, you have probably copy-pasted the output of a terminal when started python. Python is working good, fix the file you are trying to import the function from